# How to reload current UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiview

I have a method I am calling from my mainview that is setting the image name of the image I want to display in a scrollview.

```
 - (void)loadImage:(NSString *)myImageName
    {
        if (myImageName == @"one") {
            imageName = myImageName;
        }
        if (myImageName == @"two") {
            imageName = myImageName;
        }
        if (myImageName == @"three") {
            imageName = myImageName;
        }

        //Reloads view here???
    }
```

I am loading the images in my viewdidload method like so

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //Create scrollview
    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.bounces = NO;

    //Create scrollviewimage
    if (imageName == @"one") {
        image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ha.png"]];
    }
    if (imageName == @"two") {
        image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"haha.png"]];
    }
    if (imageName == @"three") {
        image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hahaha.png"]];
    }



    containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 550)];
    //Add subview
    [containerView addSubview:image];
    //initViews
    scrollView.contentSize = containerView.frame.size;
    [scrollView addSubview:containerView];

    //scrolling
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 31.0;
    [scrollView setZoomScale:scrollView.minimumZoomScale];

    //highrachy
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

}
```

What happens when I set the imagename from the parentview from a tableviewcell selection I pass down the nsstring into loadImage.. then load image sets the name in viewdidload.. however what is happening is that only the first selection dose anything.. so you will always see the first image you are selecting.. so if you pick image two every other image you select will show image two..

any help would be great.

here is what the parentview cell selection looks like

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Sets the back button for the new view that loads (this overrides the usual parentview name with "Back")
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];

    if (!self.detailViewController) {
        self.detailViewController = [[ICDDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ICDDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            _detailViewController.imageName = @"one";
            //        NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
        }
        if (indexPath.section == 1) {
            _detailViewController.imageName = @"two";
            //        NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
        }
        if (indexPath.section == 2) {
            _detailViewController.imageName = @"three";
            //        NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
        }
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use myImageName == @"three".  There's a special method for comparing strings.

try this:

```
if ([myImageName isEqualToString:@"three"]) {
    [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:myImageName]];
}
```

If there is a file extension, do this:

```
NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",myImageName];
[image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imagePath]];
```

By the way, you are still posting the old code you had in your other question.  You are retaining your detailView in your original class instead of releasing and creating a new instance.  Take out the if (!detailView) statements.

Update: the only other option is to take the assignments out of the large if( ) block.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Sets the back button for the new view that loads (this overrides the usual parentview name with "Back")
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];

    if (!self.detailViewController) {
        self.detailViewController = [[ICDDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ICDDetailViewController" bundle:nil];


    //MY CHANGES HERE:
    //If you left these if () statements inside the original code, they would never
    //fire if the detailView was already instantiated once.  Does this make sense?
    }  // <--- moved the bracket up here
        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            _detailViewController.imageName = @"one";
            //        NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
        }
        if (indexPath.section == 1) {
            _detailViewController.imageName = @"two";
            //        NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
        }
        if (indexPath.section == 2) {
            _detailViewController.imageName = @"three";
            //        NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
        }
    //}  <--- commented this one out
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

The only other way is this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Sets the back button for the new view that loads (this overrides the usual parentview name with "Back")
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
    //commented out the next line, don't need to check to see if it's already present
    //just create a new instance to push on the stack
    //if (!self.detailViewController) {
        self.detailViewController = [[ICDDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ICDDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            _detailViewController.imageName = @"one";
            //        NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
        }
        if (indexPath.section == 1) {
            _detailViewController.imageName = @"two";
            //        NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
        }
        if (indexPath.section == 2) {
            _detailViewController.imageName = @"three";
            //        NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
        }
    //} <--- get rid of this bracket since the original if () was commented out
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you aren't ever releasing your instance of UIScrollView.  So, when you go to reuse it the second time, viewDidLoad doesn't get called again.  That means your 'image' variable never gets reassigned a new image.

To check to see if this is the case, try putting an NSLog call in your viewDidLoad method and see if it gets called the second time you select from the tableViewCell.

If this is the case, there are a few options for fixing it. Are you using ARC?

Comment: I just put an nslog in each of the if statments inside viewdidload and like the image the only one that returns is the first one that is selected.. only once.

Comment: Great, so now you know what the problem is, you just need to fix it.  I'd recommend just directly setting the image property for your 'image' class with [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] at the end of your loadImage: method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just updating the `UIImageView`?

```
- (void)loadImage:(NSString *)myImageName
{
    if (myImageName == @"one") {
        imageName = myImageName;
    }
    if (myImageName == @"two") {
        imageName = myImageName;
    }
    if (myImageName == @"three") {
        imageName = myImageName;
    }

    [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
}
```